# Importing sub-sub-packages within a Python application

Tags: python, python-module, python-import

I'm writing a modular application that will dynamically import modules at runtime based upon launch parameters, etc. To keep things organised, I have the following directory structure:

```
    myapp/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── main.py
    ├── utils.py
    ├──modules/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── iptables/
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── iptables.py
        │   ├── [other files/directories/configuration...]
        │   └── tests
        │       ├── iptables_tests.py
        ├── layer4/
        │   ├── __init__.py
        │   ├── layer4.py
        │   ├── [other files/directories/configuration...]
        │   └── tests
        │       ├── layer4_tests.py
```

I'm trying to accomplish the following:

- `main.py` should be able to do something like `from modules.layer4 import Layer4Manager`, with `Layer4Manager` being a class inside `modules/layer4/layer4.py`. I'd like to do this without including the actual code inside `__init__.py` if possible, as there will be other scripts/files in the same directory, so it makes sense for them to be grouped together in directories (this is also why the scripts aren't just in the `modules` directory).
- `iptables.py` and `layer4.py` should be able to import functions from `utils.py`.
- Tests using the Python unittest framework and Nose should run correctly by, for example, `iptables_tests.py` should be able to run`from myapp.modules.iptables import IPTablesController` and `from myapp.utils import UtilityFunction`.

I've been battling with this for a few hours now and I'm unable to get all three of the above items working at the same time. Using `from layer4 import *` or the `__all__` variable inside `modules/layer4/__init__.py` breaks the tests, as they are unable to `from myapp.utils import UtilityFunction`.

Blanking `modules/*/__init__.py` stops me from being able to `from myapp.modules.layer4 import Layer4Manager`.

I've tried several other combinations and I think I'm just making matters worse. I'm targeting Python 2.6. I'm guessing some kind of relative import will make things easier, but I'm not sure how they would work with the two-level directory structure I'm using here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Also, the tests/ directories contain blank `__init__.py`'s, although I'm not sure if this is necessary or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `main/__init__.py` because you don't want to make `myapp` a package and when you will execute main.py, myapp will be automatically added to python path.

Other than that it looks fine, you should be able to directly import modules from subpackages if you put the correct paths e.g.

```
import utils
from modules.layer4 import layer4
```

I created a similar structure and it works well e.g.

```
$ cat myapp/main.py 
import utils
from modules.layer4 import layer4
from modules.iptables import iptables

$ cat myapp/modules/iptables/iptables.py
from modules.layer4 import layer4

$ cat myapp/modules/layer4/layer4.py
import utils
```

and all this works without error

Comment: Thanks, you put me on the right track by removing the `myapp/__init__.py`. I think that was messing things up further down the line. With that removed and some import changes I've managed to get it working!

Answer (score 0):

"from modules.layer4.layer4 import Layer4Manager" should work for your first import - does it not, or is that not sufficient?

Does your utils.py also import from any of the modules below it?  If so, you may be creating circular imports (just a guess, but that may go to why you can't get all the imports working at once...).  If so, you may need to move the imports into code blocks where they won't be executed on import of utils.py.  That may explain why the tests break when you do the import in __init__.py.

Otherwise, if you want "from modules.layer4 import Layer4Manager" to work, you really need to bring it into the __init__.py somehow - possibly by imports in there.

Comment: I would prefer the latter `from modules.layer4 import Layer4Manager` primarily because this looks cleaner than using `modules.layer4.layer4`. utils.py doesn't import any modules from the child directories.

Comment: How about "from modules.layer4 import layer4" followed by referring to "layer4.Layer4Manager"?

If utils.py doesn't import (directly or via other imports) anything from the child modules, then that UtilityFunction should work - what's the error you get when the tests try and import it?